# Cancel repeating localnotification on weekends [ReactNative]

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling repeating(day) local notification on time set by user.
I want to provide the user with a option such that he/she can disable these notification for weekends(Saturday,Sunday).
Is it possible ? If yes, then please guide me in the right direction.

I am using this [library](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/) and this is the code i am using to schedule the local notification.

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
              message: 'good morning',
              date: date,
              smallIcon: "ic_notification",
              color: "#3591EC",
              repeatType:'day',
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested by [Chris Allwein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014580/cancel-repeating-localnotification-on-weekends-reactnative/45014746?noredirect=1#comment77003958_45014746) instead of canceling the recurring daily notification, i scheduled  recurring weekly notifications as chosen by the user. This is how i did it. Hope it helps someone.

```
let days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'];
        for(let i=0; i<days.length; i++){
            let date = moment(days[i],"dddd");
            Notification.schedule(message,date);
        }
```

and in `Notification.schedule()` i did the following

```
schedule(message, date){
let date = new Date(date);
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
              fireDate: date.getTime(),
              alertBody: message,
              repeatInterval:'week'

          });
        }
```

Comment: How can I schedule repeatInterval to 'month' ? If I set repeatInterval to 'month', then its not working in iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications(details)
```

The details parameter allows you to specify a dictionary that can be used to match one or more scheduled notifications.  So in your case, something like:

```
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({date: DateToCancel})
```

Comment: how can i cancel the notification for every coming 'Saturday and Sunday' ? Could u explain it with an example

Comment: It sounds like your best strategy in that case is to cancel the recurring daily notification, and instead schedule recurring weekly notifications for only those days of the week.